# Two months in the Caribbean - With Diving Available

Tags: budget, accommodation, beaches, caribbean, diving

I am searching for some simple accommodation on some Caribbean islands, in Costa Rica, Panama or similar to stay for 2 months. It should be near to the beach, and I'd like to learn diving, so a diving school should be close by.

It should also be cheap and clean, calm, not a victim of mass tourism.

I want to go from January until the end of February.

Do you know such places?

Comment: have tidied up the grammar and reworded the headline to focus on your requirements, let me know if I've interpreted anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

You should have a look at the [Commonwealth of Dominica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominica). Hotels are not really cheap. However, there are some guesthouses and cottages in the capital Roseau, but also in other villages around the island. I was there three years ago, but I stayed in a hotel, so I cannot comment on guesthouses.

Dominica has some nice diving spots. There is no real mass tourism in Dominica. In this respect, the biggest annoyance you could have are the big cruise ships calling in Roseau. Note that in January/February this can happen 2-3 times a week. But it is easy to escape the crowds ... Just go to less popular places. If you want somewhere really calm, you should settle down in Portsmouth. There you will find accommodations and also a diving school.

If you are not diving, you can do some hiking and enjoy Dominica's wild and splendid nature!

Here is a [website](http://avirtualdominica.com), where you will find some information on accommodation and things to do in Dominica.